# Change scale of Rectangle inside Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, shapes

I have a `Canvas` with a `Rectangle`:

```
<Canvas>
   <Rettangle/>
</Canvas>
```

And I want that, when i resize my Canvas, the Rectangle keep the same relative position, for example:

```
----------------------------------------
|                                      |
|                                      |
|           ____                       |
|          |    |                      |
|          |____|                      |
|                                      |
|--------------------------------------


--------------------
|                   |
|   ___             |
|   |__|            |
|                   |
|-------------------
```

How can I do?

Comment: You just want rectangle's position to be relative or it's size too? from the image it looks both.

Comment: @akjoshi both, size too.

Comment: If you apply a ScaleTransform to the Canvas, I think it'll do this.

Comment: My Canvas is inside a Window, when I resize the Window the Canvas is resized too, I don't apply any Transformations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not put the whole stuff in a [Viewbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms617883)?

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
    <Canvas Width="400" Height="300">
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Blue"/>
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Why the `Canvas` has specific `Width` and `Height`? I want that `Canvas` fills all the available space inside my `Window`.

Comment: So if my Windows is resized I have to change the size of my Canvas dynamically?

Comment: You can give it any width and height you like. It just has to have a fixed size compared to the contained Rectangle. Canvas size and Rectangle size and position must have a certain pre-defined relation. You could as well set Canvas.Width=1.0 and Rectangle.Width=0.25.

Comment: That's what the Viewbox does. Just try the sample XAML. Use the Viewbox as top-level container in a Window.

Answer (score 1):

The best possible solution is to create your own custom canvas and implement the re-sizing and re-positioning using some of the techniques mentioned in these questions -

[How do you do relative positioning in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158175/how-do-you-do-relative-positioning-in-wpf)

[WPF: Setting the Width (and Height) as a Percentage Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717299/wpf-setting-the-width-and-height-as-a-percentage-value?sort=votes#sort-top)

But for me this functionality looks very similar to zooming; in case your window is only having Canvas you can try to use following ZoomableCanvas from Kael Rowan and explicitly zoom-in/zoom-out when your window re-sizes:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaelr/archive/2010/07/29/zoomablecanvas.aspx