# The objects inside the xaml form are being scrambled (resized or hidden) after resizing main window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a problem in resizing the main window of my app.xaml form: after resizing it, the objects (buttons,combo boxes, textboxes, etc) inside the form are being resized, hidden or moved to another place in the form. I just want to resize the main window not the other objects. in the other words, I want to **unlink** these two (main window & other objects) from each other. after doing that, I can resize main window and then, manually move the objects to their new place in the form. the code of the form is given below.

```
<Window x:Class="WPFClient.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="550" Width="834" MaxHeight="550" MaxWidth="834" MinHeight="550" MinWidth="834">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Color="LightSlateGray" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.5"/>
                <GradientStop Color="LightSlateGray" Offset="0.9"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>


        <Label x:Name="loginLabelUName" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="179,200,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70">User Name:
        </Label>
        <TextBox x:Name="loginTxtBoxUName" Height="23" Margin="277,200,313,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Label x:Name="loginLabelIP"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="179,232,0,255"  Width="70">Service IP:</Label>
        <TextBox x:Name="loginTxtBoxIP" Margin="277,232,313,0" Text="41.235.135.104" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Button x:Name="loginButtonConnect"  Background="Transparent" Margin="277,0,313,222" Click="buttonConnect_Click"  Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Connect</Button>
        <Label x:Name="loginLabelStatus" Height="44" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontFamily="Jokerman" FontSize="20" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="167" Margin="0,0,40,71">Offline</Label>
        <ComboBox x:Name="loginComboBoxImgs" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,200,197,222" Width="98" Background="Transparent" />
        <Label x:Name="loginLabelTitle" Height="57" FontFamily="Jokerman" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Margin="16,16,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="293">WCF / WPF Chat App.</Label>
<Polyline x:Name="loginPolyLine"  StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="White" Points="140,90 140,300 700,300 700,90 140,90" Margin="-9,42,116,165" />



        <ListBox x:Name="chatListBoxMsgs" Margin="10,62,167,84" />
    <ListBox x:Name="chatListBoxNames" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,62,10,84" Width="139" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="chatCheckBoxWhisper" Height="15" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,37,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Foreground="White" FontSize="12">Whisper Mode</CheckBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="chatTxtBoxType" Height="39" Margin="10,0,313,9" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
    <Button x:Name="chatButtonSend" Click="chatButtonSend_Click" Height="39" Margin="0,0,167,9" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="136">Send</Button>
    <Button x:Name="chatButtonDisconnect"  Click="chatButtonDisconnect_Click" Height="39" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,9"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="139">Disconnect</Button>
    <Image x:Name="chatCurrentImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" Stretch="Fill" Width="60" Height="70" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label x:Name="chatLabelCurrentUName" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="87,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85"  Foreground="White"></Label>
    <Label x:Name="chatLabelCurrentStatus" Height="23" Margin="87,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="85"></Label>
    <Label x:Name="chatLabelWritingMsg" Height="30" Margin="10,0,167,49" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="Gray"></Label>
    <Button x:Name="chatButtonSendFile" Click="chatButtonSendFile_Click" Background="Transparent" Height="23" Margin="270,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="105">Send File</Button>
    <Label x:Name="chatLabelSendFileStatus" Height="28" Margin="270,32,316,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Label>
    <Button x:Name="chatButtonOpenReceived" Click="chatButtonOpenReceived_Click" Background="Transparent" Height="23" Margin="382,10,313,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">Open Received Files</Button>



    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Have you heard of relative size in wpf??[Relative](http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/star-sizing/) and [Relative sizing](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30904/WPF-Layouts-A-Visual-Quick-Start) may help

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is occurring is because you are explicitly setting `Margin` properties on your elements.

```
Margin="277,232,313,0"
```

These margins are relative to the parent `Grid`. So the code above says:

*Place the element 277 from the left, 232 from the top, 313 from the right and 0 from the bottom.*

Therefore, when the `Grid` gets resized, these margins will be recalculated, and thus, screw up the positioning of the elements.

To combat this, you should look into using **relative** positioning. There is already an answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158175/how-do-you-do-relative-positioning-in-wpf).

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution.when I select an object like button or ..., a small **link** icon(similar to above Hyperlink icon) appears on each edge of the object (or on grids around it). by clicking on these icons, you can change them into **Unlinked** or **Linked** situation. now when you want to resize the main window, you should do the following:
1. move all the objects to the new place you want in the form.
2. select the objects one after another and click on link icon at the side that you want to decrease the main window's width or height from that side.for example, if you want to decrease the width/height of the window from right/down side, you should unlink every "right/down" side link icon.
3. resize the width or height of main window by dragging its edge according to the 2nd step example. you can see that resizing window does not affect other objects at all.